# Disable all Kivy elements in loop, enable certain elements

Tags: python, for-loop, kivy, disable

Im trying to disable all GUI widgets except a few:

```
for i_d in self.ids: #Disables all GUI elements
    #if [i_d] != 'lblConnection' or [i_d] != 'swCOM' or [i_d] != 'swSYS' or [i_d] != 'btnTestConnection':
    self.ids[i_d].disabled = True

#Enables a few elements
self.ids.lblConnection.disabled = False
self.ids.swCOM.disabled = False
self.ids.swSYS.disabled = False
self.ids.btnTestConnection.disabled = False
```

As you can see i tried playing around with an if condition, but im fine with enabling the widgets manually line by line. The disabling part works, the enabling not (Whole GUI stays disabled).

Comment: Keep in mind that if you disable a widget, all its children are disabled too. You can't enable any of these children if their parent is still disabled...

Comment: Ah good point! Maybe ill rather disable all my elements manually then?

Comment: Seems safer..;o)